# Result set already closed

Tags: hibernate, resultset

I upgrade spring and hibernate .I am getting result set closed error, below is error and my code:

### error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not get next iterator result

caused by java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed

### code:

public final DrugPairVa findDrugPair(long rtgenId1, long rtgenId2, long interactionId) {
Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(FIND_DP_QUERY);
//Fortify Access Control: Database
query.setLong("rtgenId1", validateLongInput(validateStringInput(String.valueOf(rtgenId1), ACCESS_CONTROL_DB)));
query.setLong("rtgenId2", validateLongInput(validateStringInput(String.valueOf(rtgenId2),ACCESS_CONTROL_DB)));

```
    String id = getAuthenticatedId(interactionId);
    query.setLong("interactionId", validateLongInput(id));
    Iterator<DrugPairVa> iter = query.iterate();
    DrugPairVa res = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;

    return res;
}
```

Upgraded Hibernate and spring and getting error